# Reversing scroll direction and elements order in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, display

this is my website
https://ganyavne.biz

i have this section in mobile:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmZ0d.png)

and i would like that the most left element of this section (you can scroll it to the left on mobile) would appear most right (reverse order)

how can it be done?

im currently using {display:flex} for that section

Thanks!!

Comment: post some code HERE, please avoid posting links to work

Comment: .smalldealsrow
    {
position: relative;
 display: flex;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
direction: rtl;
apple-overflow-scrolling: touch;
html-overflow-scrolling: touch;
webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

Comment: Edit your question to include code

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your container div:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

Comment: thanks! it does reverses the order, but then the scroll goes to the right instead of to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe flex-direction:row-reverse on the flex container